# What happen when a value of an Array is Erased while Looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was asking my self : **What happens to the emplacement of the array if an erased is done while looping into that array ?**

Suppose you've got a bunch of elements arranged in an array.

Now suppose you've got multiple identical elements and you want to erase them.

You're doing a classical double loop and when an element is found to be duplicated you erase it...

**What happen to your array in this case ?** Does the element just after take the place of your erased element ? Does the element take a null value ?

Here is a schema for better comprehension (sorry I'm far from an artist :) )

[image]

### Exemple of code in JavaScript :

```
arrayCity = $.makeArray($('.cityName'));
for(i=0; i < arrayCity.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0; j < arrayCity.length; j++)
    {
        if (arrayCity[i].innerHTML == arrayCity[j].innerHTML)
        {
            arrayCity.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And to continue on it; I've been told that it is better in this case to iterate in reverse. But in this case my incomprehension is even bigger; what happens if you erase, lets say, the first index of your array ? Will it push up the whole array ? In this case what happens to your first loop .. ?

Here is a second schema to illustrate the second part of my question (as ugly as the first :/ I'm afraid )

[image]

I'll be glad to have a bit of explanation on those case. Thank you for reading !

Comment: Since you already wrote the code, you could easily just test it in the console.

Comment: if you want to filter out empties you may want to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

Comment: @ray -- Array.splice alters the original array. `var x = [1,2,3]; x.splice(0, 1); console.log(x); //[2, 3]`

Comment: my bad. i was thinking of slice. first comment edited accordingly.

Comment: @Nit If I'am taking the time to asking it maybe is it because I want an explanation not a simple observation...

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an element from the array all of the following elements are shifted down one index.  Looping through the array in reverse can prevent you from skipping elements.  For example if you have an array [1, 2, 3] and you delete the item at index 0 your array will be [2, 3].  You will then step to index 1 and miss item 2 (now at index 0).  If you need to make sure you hit every element you can try looping in reverse or using Array.proto.forEach().

Comment: Not the first time I see something about array.prototype . . what is it exactly ?

Comment: forEach() makes no such guarantees about not skipping: `[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(a,b,c){if(b==1) c.splice(b,1); console.log(a)});`

Comment: So what do you advice me to do ? Using a revert loop is the best way to get all my element ?

Comment: That's true @dandavis, which is I guess why it's best not to modify an array in a forEach and use map instead. Baldráni It depends on what you're doing inside the loop, but it sounds like a reverse loop will work for you.